# Change background-color of div from left border to right by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like change color of a `div`, starting from left border, by clicking a button.

I put an example that do a similar thing but just when mouse hovers on the div.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/3/).
I'd like a thing like that.

This is my code: 
**HTML**:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div  class="abc" id="d" style="width:150px; height: 150px;">
    <button onClick="setNew()">Click me</button>
    <button onClick="goBack()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function setNew() {
   var id = "dv";
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
function setNew() {
   var id = "d";
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

**CSS**:

```
.abc {
  background-color:white;
  transition: background-color 800ms linear;  
}
```

Comment: example uses a linear-gradient, you don't, it will just fade from color to color. - test with focus on link http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/1866/

Comment: You mean, the color transition should change only when you click, instead of when you hover?

Comment: Thank you @GCyrillus for your reply! Anyway I want to do that by js function because I want call a function in other cases, not only when the user click a button.
I would like that the color changing start every time from left and ending to right, either that the transition is white-blue or blue-white.
Could you help me again?

Comment: Mark, the point is to use a gradient and reset background-position. i used focus, use onclick event :)

Answer (score 0):

This does when you click instead of when you hover

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.skillsDouble {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.skillsDouble li a {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #ff3232;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.skillsDouble li a:focus {
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.skillsDouble li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="skillsDouble">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Automation</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TDD</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--End skills double-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery way u can just do a event click when u click, add a class in your div who have your css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("li").click(function(){
      $("li").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
  })
})
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.skillsDouble {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.skillsDouble li {
    width:100px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: #ff3232;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 2s ease;
}
.skillsDouble .active{
    background-position:left bottom;
}
.skillsDouble li a {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skillsDouble">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Automation</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TDD</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--End skills double-->
```